# Java : If statement to process amount you want whilst discarding the rest?

Tags: java, if-statement, storage

I have the following script :

```
public void addcheese(int addcheese) {
    if (cheeseamount + addcheese < mincapacity) {
        System.out.println("Sorry no more cheese can be removed.");
    } else if (cheeseamount + addcheese <= maxcapacity) {
        if ((cheeseamount + addcheese > 1900) && (cheeseamount + addcheese < 2000)) {
            System.out.println("Warning : The box is nearing it's maximum capacity.");
        }
        cheeseamount = cheeseamount + addcheese;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("This storage box has reached its maximum capacity. You cannot fill it any more");
    }
}
```

(Note : In constructor maxcapacity = 2000)

The script works as it should, however there is a problem in that if i was to input a number like 3400, it would still print the message *"This storage box has reached its max..."* without adding anything. How would i edit the script to, in this case, add to the box up until the maxcapacity, and discard the excess amount. Thank you.

Comment: Your spacing is odd in parts which is making it difficult to parse.  This may be an accepted style; I've just never seen it before.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want.  But if you fill the box up to the maximum capacity and discard the excess, what will `cheeseamount` be afterwards?  It's a very simple answer, if I understand the problem correctly.  You should just be able to use a simple assignment inside the last `else` block.

Comment: `cheeseamount = Math.min(maxcapacity, cheeseamount + addcheese);`?

Comment: @fge You don't even need that. Inside the `else` you'd need only `cheeseamount = maxcapacity;`.

Comment: @Thor84no but with this you don't even need the last else

Comment: @fge But then you'd change the program beyond what he asked for. There's nothing here indicating you don't still need to print the message saying it has reached maximum capacity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
public void addcheese(int addcheese) 
{
    final int target = cheeseamount + addcheese;

    if (target < mincapacity) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, no cheese can be removed");
        return;
    }

    if (target >= maxcapacity) {
        cheeseamount = maxcapacity;
        System.out.println("Box is full");
        return;
    }

    cheeseamount = target;
    if (cheeseamount > 1900)
        System.out.println("Warning, box is nearing its maximum capacity");
}
```

Notes:

- left as an exercise to the reader: warn about the amount of cheese wasted!
- naming conventions: Java uses camelCase; preferrably those should be `addCheese`, `cheeseAmount` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add another if else with this condition:

```
else if (cheeseamount != maxcapacity && cheeseamount + addcheese > maxcapacity) {
    cheeseamount = maxcapacity;
    System.out.println("Warning : The box just reached it's maximum capacity.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is by modifying your else statement. In the else statement you can simply set the amount of cheese to the maximum amount, essentially adding as much cheese as possible and discarding the rest:

```
else {
            cheeseamount = 2000;
            System.out.println("This storage box has now reached its maximum capacity.");

       }
```

However here you are losing the amount of cheese that you discarded. If you wanted to retain that number you could just create a new variable:

```
else {
            int extraCheese = cheeseamount + addcheese - 2000;
            cheeseamount = 2000;
            System.out.println("This storage box has now reached its maximum capacity.");

       }
```

A side note: It would be a good idea to save your max capacity and any other magic numbers as constants. Magic numbers are basically random numbers that appear throughout your code that anyone else looking at your code couldn't make sense out of. By creating a constant with a descriptive name you can make it clear to other programmers what the number represents and you can also modify it easily in the future.